# Thermodynamics and Special Relativity

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, temperature, speed-of-light

What happens to the temperature of a body (not in the body frame) as it approaches the speed of light? My thinking is that the molecules will necessarily 'prefer' (as a natural consequence of the basic effects of SR - yes, I am handwaving at the moment and not giving detail just to avoid extra text) a direction of movement, rendering the conventional notion of temperature less adequate.

Comment: In the frame of the body, nothing happens.

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-17526-4

Comment: There is an article with some discussion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_heat_conduction
and at least one study claiming to show a deeper connection between the speed of light and the 2nd Law of Thermo.  Haven't really seen further confirmation in mainstream physics news.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens to the temperature of a body (not in the body frame) as it approaches the speed of light?

As discussed in [this article](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-017-17526-4), no one can tell you the answer, at least unless you choose a specific definition of temperature.

In fact, over the years, at least three different transformations have been proposed by reputable theorists:
$$
T' = \gamma\; T\;,\tag{1}
$$
$$
T' = T/\gamma\;,\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
T' = T\;.\tag{3}
$$

Equations (1), (2), and (3) are all clearly inconsistent with each other. As discussed in the linked article, it is amusing that Einstein believed that each of Equations (1), (2), and (3) were correct at some point in his life.

Experimental data is required to say for sure, and as mentioned above, there are various definitions of temperature that can be applied.